# How to change tag 'UNKNOWN' when doing syslog from GLOG?

Tags: c++, syslog, glog

I am writing syslog using GLOG 
using [GLOG](https://google-glog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/glog.html) documentation 
For example I have following code :

```
 SYSLOG(INFO)<<"Syslog testing";
```

but int log file I see

```
 Nov 18 16:39:03 xyz UNKNOWN[12807]: Syslog testing
```

Can anybody please tell me Is there any way to change UNKNOWN to my input string?.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you haven't initialized GLOG yet. Before calling anything in the glog lib, run the InitGoogleLogging function. The documentation states you should pass argv[0] from main (see https://github.com/google/glog), which *should* be the name of your executable. However, you can pass what you desire here and that is what you will see in syslog.

e.g.

```
google::InitGoogleLogging("MyProgramName");
SYSLOG(INFO) << "Starting my program!";
```

result:

```
Apr 29 18:38:28 ccc39bda5f31 MyProgramName[2927]: Starting my program!
```